# JSON_VALUE() stopped working in SQL Azure v12?

Tags: sql, json, azure

Since yesterday the function `JSON_VALUE()` is not working anymore in SQL Azure v12.

Who knows why this disappeared and/or when it will come back?

Probably associated: I'm getting this 12.0 instead of 13.0 version on *@@version* now ?!?

`SELECT *@@version* as SqlAzureVersion`

*Result*:

> Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Dec  2 2015 00:01:31   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

`SELECT **JSON_VALUE**(N'{"a": "b"}', N'$.a')`

*Result*:

> 'JSON_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database now officially supports JSON functions see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-json-in-azure-sql-database/